# Let $Y\sim F_{\theta}$. When $g(Y, \theta)$ that does not depend on $\theta$?

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, transformation, uniform-distribution, invariance

Let $Y$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$, with distribution function belonging to a family $\{F_{\theta}, \theta\in\Theta\}$ is a parametric family of distribuitiuons (e.g. normal with unknown parameters $\theta= (\mu, \Sigma)$. You can put some simple assumptions such as continuity etc if you want).

Let $m=1$. I am looking for a function $g: \mathbb{R}^k\times \Theta \to \mathbb{R}^m$ satisfying both:

1. $W:= g(Y, \theta)$ is a random variable whose distribution under $F_{\theta}$ does *not* depend on $\theta$. (if we put there correct $\theta$, then $W$ does not matter which $\theta$ was the correct one)
2. $W_{\theta}:= g(Y, \theta)$ satisfy that $W_{\theta_1}\overset{D}{\neq}W_{\theta_2}$ for each $\theta_1\neq\theta_2\in\Theta$

For example, if $k=1$ then $g(Y, \theta):=F_{\theta}(Y)$ satisfy that $W\sim UNIF(0,1)$ (first point is ok) and $W_{\theta_1}\overset{D}{\neq}W_{\theta_2}$ if $\{F_{\theta}, \theta\in\Theta\}$ does not contain two identical functions (I think). I am trying to generalize this and find similiar result for at least $k=2$.

I have a feeling it is not possible for $m=1$. What about $m=k$? (i.e. $W\in\mathbb{R}^k$).

Comment: Your example is already the case $m=1$ right? Your question isn't completely clear to me. Do you want examples of situations where such a function $g$ exists, or a general way to construct $g$ that "always" works (under some mild assumptions)?

Comment: construction of $g$ under "as general and practical" assumptions as possible

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something. If condition 1 holds for all $\Theta^{\star}$, then the function g(.,.) is constant in its second argument which contradicts 2.

Comment: there is only one $\theta^\star$ which represents the ground truth. Function $g(Y, \theta)$ does depend on $\theta$. however, for this one specific $\theta^\star$, distribution of $W$ does not depend on $\theta^\star\in\Theta$. Did it answered your question?

Comment: Yes, it answers my question.

Comment: The question is pretty unclear. The explanation of 1 in the comments just makes no sense. Of course, a single fixed function does not depend on $\theta^\star$. My guess of what OP wanted to ask is as follows. There is a family of measures $\mathrm P_\theta$, and we want to construct $g(y,\theta)$ such that: 1) the distribution of $g(Y,\theta)$ **under $\mathrm P_\theta$** does not depend on $\theta$; 2) for any $\theta'\neq \theta$, $g(Y,\theta')$ and $g(Y,\theta)$ have different distributions under $\mathrm P_\theta$.

Comment: @zhoraster thanks for the clarification. Yes, I mean... My formulation was that if $\theta^\star$ is the true value, then the distribution of $g(Y, \theta^star)$ doesn't depend on $\theta^\star$. I think that is equivalent to saying that  $g(Y,\theta)$ under $P_\theta$ does not depend on $\theta$. But yes, your sentence is better said, so I rewrote it

Comment: Once more, a single function does not "depend" on anything (except its input). Simply because there's just one. After your edit the question didn't become much better, as 1 and 2 do not quite agree.

Comment: So what do you need? A multivariate version of the quantile transform?

Comment: I need multivariate Probability integral transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform . At univariate case, the PIT is always uniform(0,1). I want the similiar thing in the multivariate setup.